# Is there a software that helps configure structured strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm using a JavaScript component that takes a 2D array as an input. There is a particular format to it, and I basically need to develop grid GUI to help configure such a string, instead of having to type it manually.

```
[
  [0,"Chart","linear"],
  [2,"3D",false],
  [1,"Labels",["Student","Business","Professional","Retired"]]
]
```

Any ideas how to build such a thing quickly?

- Add and remove "rows"
- Cols have a particular format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost certain that Yahoo User Interface (YUI) component exists to do just that. Looks like [Datatable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) might help you.

As an alternative, it should be easy enough to roll your own:

- A table element
- A JavaScript method to create a new row piece of DOM
- An HTML control to add a row (+button), with onClick or somesuch calling the above method
- A method to loop over all rows in the table and export the data into needed format.
  [ which format I would strongly suggest to be JSON ]

Comment: Added a link to a component that seems to be usable (full disclosure - I never used DataTable, so i'm basing this only on reviewing the capoabilities listed on YUI site.

Comment: If you need info on the rolling your own part, please be more specific on which items you need help with. Thanks

Comment: Fine, though you seem to be teaching me programming. I wanted more than just a datagrid, something like an MS-Access editor, where cells can be drop-down lists, etc. I thought someone would've created some sort of SDK for such structured-string configuring.

Comment: Hmm... I'm tempted to reply in the spirit of "Someone did create it - MicroSoft" :).... But I'll restrain myself, since I'm not certain if Access has web interface like most other office apps. :)
Also, is it possible that DataTable allows you to have custom input elements in a grid, or you can manually substitute them.

Comment: Actually, my last comment led me to think - may be Google Docs's spreadsheet has components you can import and use in your app? I never used them but if they are Excel replacements like they claim to be, they should allow this functionality.